# Filter inside QUERY based on substring

Tags: google-sheets

So I am using a combination of query() and importdata() to pull data from another file. A simplified version of the results I get are the columns Supplier and Week where Week would be of the form WK01, WK11, WK43 etc.

How can I filter the Week column so that I only get weeks which have a week below WK10 in my results? In normal SQL you could just do something like `where right(Week,2)<10` and this would return only results where the Week would be below WK10 but not sure how to do such a substring filter in Google Sheets' Query function.

Comment: Could you show us a sample of your data and you current QUERY?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2):

you can use regex like:

```
where Col2 matches 'WK0[1-9]'
```

or:

```
where Col2 matches 'WK0.'
```